# WSO2 ESB Proxy stop replacing %26 with &

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to send these parameters to domain

> domain/page?param1=xxx&param2=yyy%26zzz

I am using proxy in wso2 for domain

> localhost:8280/services/proxyfordomain/page?param1=xxx&param2=yyy%26zzz

Endpoint of proxyfordomain is domain

Proxy is replacing %26 with &

Actual URL to be logged in console is:

```
To domain/page?param1=xxx&param2=yyy%26zzz
```

But URL logged in console is :

```
To domain/page?param1=xxx&param2=yyy&zzz
```

Here param2 will take `yyy%26zzz` format values
but not `yyy&zzz`

How to stop WSO2 from replacing?

Thanks for spending your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script mediator configuration to replace 'yyy&zzz' with 'yyy%26zzz'.

```
<script language="js">var url = mc.getTo().toString();
var newURL = url.replace("yyy&amp;zzz","yyy%26zzz");
mc.setTo(newURL);</script>
```